# Volume widget like iOS - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

I want to create a volume control widget like iOS. Below is the picture for reference
[image]

Is there any way to create the same without using any plugins or packages?

I tried to replicate it but couldn't think of the logic for it.
Below is the code that I currently have.

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
    height: 150.0,
    width: 30.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        const BoxShadow(
          color: Color(0xffbebebe),
        ),
        BoxShadow(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          offset: const Offset(1.5, 1.5),
          blurRadius: 2.0,
          spreadRadius: -2,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

And the result is this
[image]

How can I fill the `Container` when the user taps on it? I thought of using a `Stack` and then looking for the user's local tap position on the `Container`, followed by setting the height of volume level indicator `Container` up to the local tap position. But the problem is, how will I manage to tap on the areas of `Container` that already have been filled, as it would have been overlapped by the current volume level indicator `Container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this with the standard [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) with a custom track shape. To make a vertical `Slider` just use the [RotatedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html).

Check it out (Also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f10754f704c83fec44e0f17c6d309d98))

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code. The custom track shape was extracted from the already existing `RoundedRectSliderTrackShape` and customized to paint the inner shadow in the inactive track.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xffebecf0),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(64.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: -1,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 350,
                child: InnerShadowSlider(trackHeight: 30),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 60),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: InnerShadowSlider(),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 60),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 350,
                  child: InnerShadowSlider(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerShadowSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final double trackHeight;
  const InnerShadowSlider({Key? key, this.trackHeight = 60}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InnerShadowSlider> createState() => _InnerShadowSliderState();
}

class _InnerShadowSliderState extends State<InnerShadowSlider> {
  var _volume = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        trackHeight: widget.trackHeight,
        overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
        thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noThumb,
        trackShape: const MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
      ),
      child: Slider(
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: _volume,
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _volume = value),
        inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape
    with BaseSliderTrackShape {
  const MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape();

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 0,
  }) {
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.activeTrackColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.thumbShape != null);
    // If the slider [SliderThemeData.trackHeight] is less than or equal to 0,
    // then it makes no difference whether the track is painted or not,
    // therefore the painting  can be a no-op.
    if (sliderTheme.trackHeight == null || sliderTheme.trackHeight! <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    final trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight!;

    // Assign the track segment paints, which are leading: active and
    // trailing: inactive.
    final ColorTween activeTrackColorTween = ColorTween(
        begin: sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor,
        end: sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
    final ColorTween inactiveTrackColorTween = ColorTween(
        begin: sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor,
        end: sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor);
    final Paint activePaint = Paint()
      ..color = activeTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;
    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()
      ..color = inactiveTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;
    final Paint leftTrackPaint;
    final Paint rightTrackPaint;
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        leftTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = activePaint;
        break;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );

    activePaint.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
      ui.Offset(trackRect.left, 0),
      ui.Offset(thumbCenter.dx, 0),
      [
        const Color(0xff0f3dea),
        const Color(0xff2069f4),
      ],
    );

    final Radius trackRadius = Radius.circular(trackRect.height / 2);

    final Paint shadow = Paint()..color = const Color(0xffb3b6c7);
    context.canvas.clipRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBR(trackRect.left, trackRect.top, trackRect.right,
          trackRect.bottom, trackRadius),
    );

    // Solid shadow color - Top elevation
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBR(trackRect.left, trackRect.top, trackRect.right,
            trackRect.bottom, trackRadius),
        shadow);

    // Bottom elevation
    shadow
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(
        BlurStyle.normal,
        ui.Shadow.convertRadiusToSigma(10),
      );

    context.canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBR(
          trackRect.left - trackHeight,
          trackRect.top + trackHeight / 2,
          trackRect.right - 0,
          trackRect.bottom + trackHeight / 2,
          trackRadius,
        ),
        shadow);

    // Shadow
    shadow
      ..color = const Color(0xfff0f1f5)
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(
        BlurStyle.normal,
        ui.Shadow.convertRadiusToSigma(15),
      );

    context.canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBR(
          trackRect.left - trackHeight,
          trackRect.top + trackHeight / 8,
          trackRect.right - trackHeight / 8,
          trackRect.bottom,
          trackRadius,
        ),
        shadow);

    // Active/Inactive tracks
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBR(
        trackRect.left,
        (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr)
            ? trackRect.top - (additionalActiveTrackHeight / 2)
            : trackRect.top,
        thumbCenter.dx,
        (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr)
            ? trackRect.bottom + (additionalActiveTrackHeight / 2)
            : trackRect.bottom,
        trackRadius,
      ),
      leftTrackPaint,
    );
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBR(
        thumbCenter.dx,
        (textDirection == TextDirection.rtl)
            ? trackRect.top - (additionalActiveTrackHeight / 2)
            : trackRect.top,
        trackRect.right,
        (textDirection == TextDirection.rtl)
            ? trackRect.bottom + (additionalActiveTrackHeight / 2)
            : trackRect.bottom,
        trackRadius,
      ),
      rightTrackPaint,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the user clicks you can wrap the widget with `IgnorePointer`.